# Using acts_as_commentable_with_threading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to get this plugin to work. I've read other threads, but I dont seem to get it.

I'm trying to make my article model commentable. This if what i have done so far:

Done all the installation correctly.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController


def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @user_who_commented = @current_user
    @comment = Comment.build_from( @article, @user_who_commented.id, "Hey guys this is my   comment!" )
  end
end
```

In articles#show:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :text %>
   <%= f.submit "Post Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
devise_for :users
  resources :dashboard
  resources :users, :only => [:index,:show,:edit,:update]
  resources :events
  resources :januscript do
    resources :quotes
  end
  resources :jmail, :only => [:index, :show]
  resources :album 
  resources :video, :only => [:index, :show]
  resources :photos
  scope '/archive' do
    resources :quotes, :only => [:index]
    resources :articles, :only => [:index,:show]
  end
  resources :comments
```

I get this error message:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add `acts_as_commentable` to your model that you want comments on. Not seeing any model code here.

**Edit:**
Did you add the nested resource in your routes for articles as well?

```
resources :articles do
    resources :comments
end
```

Comment: I've added acts_as_commentable in Article

Comment: Edited my original answer.